# Rearranging data frame from column names to key value pairs

Tags: r, data

If I have data like this in R:

```
> a = data.frame(a = c(1, 2),
               b = c(3, 4))
> a
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

but I would like to have it like this:

```
> b = data.frame(k = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
+                v = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
> b
  k v
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 b 3
4 b 4
```

How can I convert the data this way?

Comment: Be aware that the OP is NOT actually forming key value pairs from the data. They are taking the columns of their original data frame and listing them sequentially. This destroys any relationships that existed in the original data. Also, their table `b` does not actually represent key-value pairs because it contains non-unique keys, which goes against the logic of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `gather()` using package `tidyr`:

```
> library(tidyr)
> 
> gather(a, key = "k", value = "v")
  k v
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 b 3
4 b 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use the `melt()` function from the `reshape2` package

```
> library(reshape2)
> 
> melt(a, variable.name="k", value.name="v")
No id variables; using all as measure variables
  k v
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 b 3
4 b 4
```

Hope this is insightful!